# b ⊙ x = c and gcd(b,n) = d. Show that d divides c.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

**Homework Question:**
Let n ∈ Z_+ be fixed. Let b,c ∈ Z and let d = gcd(b,n). Suppose the equation [b]⊙[x] = [c] has a solution [a] in Z_n, ie [b]⊙[a] = [c], where [a] ∈ Z_n.

Show that d divides c.

---

I am stuck on how to approach this, can someone give me a hint? More specifically I don't know what to do with this piece of information: [b]x=[c].
Thanks in advance.
P.S. apologies on any bad formatting

---

My attempt:
Writing the gcd as a linear combination we have d = bp + nq, where p,q ∈ Z.
We can also write [b]⊙[x]=[c] as bx ≡ c (modn)
If x is a solution, then bx = c + ny where y ∈ Z.
Then c = bx - ny
To show d divides c:
bx - ny = k(bp + nq) where k ∈ Z
Thus bx - ny = bkp + nkq
Hence bk and nk both divide c so the linear combination also divides c.

Comment: Suggestion:
Maybe you can try to unpack the definitions of these objects and the equation.
I would also ask you to think about what nice properties there are about the gcd.

You can modify your question with these ideas and I think that you will be in a position for someone to give you more constructive feedback.

Comment: @user357980 thank you, I tried my best with your advice.

Comment: The first part looks good: 
"Since d|b and d|n we have b = d⋅r and n = d⋅s for r,s ∈ Z.
Then writing the gcd as a linear combination we have d = bp + nq, where p,q ∈ Z."
However, you then try to mess around with both of these equations alone and so you do not solve the problem because you did not touch the important fact that  [b]⊙[a] = [c].
Write out what this means as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you write $[b]\odot[x]=[c]$ can be translated into
$$
bx\equiv c\pmod{n}
$$
Suppose $x$ is a solution, so $bx=c+ny$ for some $y$. Then
$$
c=bx-ny
$$
Conclude.